# Access Denied: Project PROJ: The user X@gmail.com does not have permission in project- pycharm use wrong email

Tags: python-2.7, email, google-bigquery, pycharm, access-denied

I have this strange issue. 
I have a private google account **X@gmail.com** with some projects on **google cloud**
and recently got a new email with accessibility to my workplace projects (also on google cloud) .
**y@work.com**.

working with **Pycharm**, I am required to tap into the company's projects and work with bigquery resources, yet I receive this error:

> HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/proj/queries?alt=json
>   returned Access Denied: Project proj: The user  X@gmail.com does not
>   have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project proj.> INFO
>   yyyy-mm-dd module.py:861] ...

clearly, Pycharm uses the wrong email- X@gmail.com.

so I went back to the:

google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init

and changed my email to the correct Email- y@work.com. and chose the right project.

regardless, **Pycharm** is **still insisting on using the bad email** and I have no clue how to fix it.

any help would be awesome.

Comment: Have your restart pycharm after changing the user email?

Comment: multiple times :(

Comment: One more option... Can you locate the file which stores your credentials? The file should be JSON.  If you have this file you can set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable in Run->Edit Configurations->Environment variables

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am able to locate it, however, perhaps I don't understand correctly-  should I put my work email  y@work.com inside this JSON ? how would it help?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create new authentication file using instructions on 
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
then change GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to point to that file.

You can switch between personal and work accounts by switching GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable.